# I'm looking for a market product that uses this patent and owner of US8047843

Tags: uspto

In reference to the patent: [US8047843](https://www.google.com/patents/US8047843)

Comment: +questions about products are off topic

Answer (score 0):

If you search for this patent number in the [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site, You can find a correspondence address which is:

```
QUARLES & BRADY LLP
Attn: IP Docket 
411 E. WISCONSIN AVENUE 
SUITE 2350 
MILWAUKEE WI 53202-4426
```